# Converting inner loops to LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

How can I re-write this nicer with `LINQ`?

```
var result = new MostOuterClass();

foreach (var item in data.Item1)
{
    var workflows = data.Item2.Where(t => t.WorkFlowName == item.Name);
    MainClass twf = new();

    foreach (var w in workflows)
    {
        TabOneClass wf = new()
        {
            Permissions = data.Item4.Where(p => p.StatusName == w.StatusName).Select(t => new LowestLeafClass()
            {
                ShortName = t.ShortName,
                StatusName = t.StatusName,
                TransitionName = t.TransitionName,

            }),
            TransitionName = w.TransitionName,
            WorkFlowName   = w.WorkFlowName,
        };
        twf.TabOneItems.Add(wf);
    }
    result.MainClassItems.Add(twf);
}
```

Here is also the used `classes` so you can see how the data is shaped:

```
public class MostOuterClass
{
    public List<MainClass> MainClassItems { get; set; } = new List<MainClass>();
}

public class MainClass
{
    public List<TabOneClass>  TabOneItems { get; set; } = new List<TabOneClass>();  
    public int                Id          { get; set; }
    public string             Name        { get; set; } = string.Empty;        
}

public class TabOneClass
{
    public IEnumerable<LowestLeafClass>    Permissions     { get; set; } = Enumerable.Empty<LowestLeafClass>();
    public string                          WorkFlowName    { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string                          StatusName      { get; set; } = string.Empty;    
    public string                          TransitionName  { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string                          Status          { get; set; } = string.Empty;        
}

public class LowestLeafClass
{
    public string ShortName            { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string StatusName           { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string TransitionName       { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add in the LINQ that demonstrates your best attempt at resolving this, and then explain what results you're getting versus what you expect. Without that info, this is asking us to "write the codez" [without any evidence of your effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Why you think LINQ will make it nicer? Yes, you may convert it to few lines, but you lose readability, so your own code will look like spaghetti of Where's and Select's

Comment: @Auditive my team lead wants it like that. That's why lol

Comment: We can agree to disagree with the requester of this requirement on "nicer" for this use case methinks code should be "understandable" first and foremost as long as the requirements are met functionally and for performance IMHO but my opinion with your lead differs obviously on what is understandable - and your having to post this question seems to reveal at least SOME truths whatever those are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all about Select and ToList. In the end, it's not better and especially not really of greater readability to write it down in a LINQ statement as compared to nested foreach. It's just a few keywords less ...
(Except that using ToList() is more effective than multiple list.Add())

```
var result = new MostOuterClass {
        MainClassItems = data.Item1.Select(item =>
            new MainClass {
                TabOneItems = data.Item2
                    .Where(t => t.WorkFlowName == item.Name)
                    .Select(w =>
                        new TabOneClass {
                            TransitionName = w.TransitionName,
                            WorkFlowName = w.WorkFlowName,
                            Permissions = data.Item4
                              .Where(p => p.StatusName == w.StatusName)
                              .Select(t => 
                                  new LowestLeafClass {
                                      ShortName = t.ShortName,
                                      StatusName = t.StatusName,
                                      TransitionName = t.TransitionName
                                  })}
                    ).ToList()
            }).ToList()
    };
```

Comment: Thanks, will plug it in now and see .

Comment: I preferred `AddRange` since `MainClassItems` and `TabOneItems` are created with empty lists, which your code throws away in preference for replacing with new lists, but very nice.

Answer (score 1):

I would flatten results with SelectMany :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApp10
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Data data = new Data();
            
            var flatten = data.Item1.SelectMany(x =>
            data.Item2.SelectMany(y => data.Item4.Select(z => new {
                 name = x.Name,
                 workFlowName = y.WorkFlowName,
                 tabtransitionName = y.TransitionName,
                 leafShortName = z.ShortName,
                 leafStatusName = z.StatusName,
                 letTransitionName = z.TransitionName
             })));

            var workflows = data.Item1.SelectMany(x => data.Item2.SelectMany(y => data.Item4.SelectMany(z => flatten.Where(a => (x.Name == y.WorkFlowName) && (z.StatusName == a.leafStatusName))))).ToList();
        }

    }
    public class Data
    {
        public List<Item1> Item1 { get; set; }
        public List<Item2> Item2 { get; set; }
        public List<Item4> Item4 { get; set; }
    }
    public class Item1
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    public class Item2
    {
        public string WorkFlowName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string TransitionName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }
    public class Item4
    {
        public string ShortName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string StatusName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string TransitionName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }
    

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure your answer makes sense. The original code built up `result` from `MainClass` objects it created by adding to `TabOneItems` and adding those to `MainClassItems` - your code assumes `result` already has content?

Comment: He wants the items hierarchically packed. Class A has collection of B, each B has a Collection of C, all Cs have a Collection of D. So SelectMany doesn't help here, since there are no collections of collections to be flattened or aggregated.

Comment: @NetMage : I fixed code.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree that this looks nicer but it is possible. It requires using a lambda body in a `Select` however, due to adding items to a property of an object in the middle. Perhaps it is time to write a recipe for converting `foreach` to LINQ.

```
var result = new MostOuterClass();

result.MainClassItems.AddRange(
    data.Item1.Select(item => {
        MainClass twf = new();
        twf.TabOneItems.AddRange(
            data.Item2.Where(t => t.WorkFlowName == item.Name)
                      .Select(w => new TabOneClass {
                          Permissions = data.Item4
                            .Where(p => p.StatusName == w.StatusName)
                            .Select(t => new LowestLeafClass() {
                                ShortName = t.ShortName,
                                StatusName = t.StatusName,
                                TransitionName = t.TransitionName,
                            })
                      })
        );
        return twf;
    })
);
```